# Algorithm to normalize the elements of an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization

If an array contains N number of elements (elements can be repeated) and the goal is to make all the elements equal by a **+1** on an element and a **-1** on another element in each iteration, how can we determine whether it's possible or not to normalize the array? What will be the optimal algorithm to solve the problem?

Ex.

For the array `1 2 3`, if I apply **+1** on `1` and **-1** on `3`, the array becomes `2 2 2`. That means it's possible in 1 iteration.

For the array `1 2 1`, it's not possible to make all the elements equal.

Comment: I seem to vaguely remember that if the sum of the elements is divisble by the number of elements, then you'll be able to do it, but I can't find a source for this, nor am I 100% it is correct.

Comment: I'll take a stab at writing up a reasoning about how and why.

Comment: @user3832066 Could you please give me a bit longer example_

Comment: 1, 9, 10, 12, 3, 7 ==> 2, 9, 10, 11, 3, 7 ==> 3, 9, 10, 10, 3, 7 ==> 4, 9, 10, 9, 3, 7 ==> 4, 9, 9, 9, 4, 7 ==> 5, 8, 9, 9, 4, 7 ==> 5, 8, 8, 9, 5, 7 ==> 6, 8, 8, 8, 5, 7 ==> 6, 7, 8, 8, 6, 7 ==> 7, 7, 7, 8, 6, 7 ==> 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7

Comment: 1 2 1 cannot be made into the same number since you're not changing the sum each iteration and the average value is 4/3, which is not a whole number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, since you're not disturbing the sum by each iteration, since you're increasing one number and decreasing another, the optimal target value is going to be the average.

If this average is a whole number, you should be able to achieve it with the iterations, however if the average is a fractional number then you will not be able to achieve it.

The number of steps is going to be the sum of the distances between each number and the target, divided by 2.

Every iteration pick one number above target and one below and apply the operations to them.

**PS!** As per commented, if all you want is answers to the following two questions:

1. Can it be done
2. What will the value be

Then the answers are:

1. Yes, provided the average number is a whole number
2. The value repeated in the whole array is the average number

Anyway, if you want the actual operations getting from the input to the target values, here's a longer example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 = 28, 28/7 = 4 (optimal target)
+           -
2 2 3 4 5 6 6
+           -
3 2 3 4 5 6 5
+           -
4 2 3 4 5 6 4
  +       -
4 3 3 4 5 5 4
  +       -
4 4 3 4 5 4 4
    +   -
4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

6 steps, let's total the distances from the first number:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
3 2 1 0 1 2 3 = 12, divided by 2 = 6
```

Here's the example from the comments on the question:

```
 1  9 10 12  3  7 = 42 / 6 = 7 (optimal target)
```

Distances:

```
 1  9 10 12  3  7
 6  2  3  5  4  0 = 20, divided by 2 = 10 (steps)

 1  9 10 12  3  7
 +  -              step 1
 2  8 10 12  3  7
 +  -              step 2
 3  7 10 12  3  7
 +     -           step 3
 4  7  9 12  3  7
 +     -           step 4
 5  7  8 12  3  7
 +     -           step 5
 6  7  7 12  3  7
 +        -        step 6
 7  7  7 11  3  7
          -  +     step 7
 7  7  7 10  4  7
          -  +     step 8
 7  7  7  9  5  7
          -  +     step 9
 7  7  7  8  6  7
          -  +     step 10
 7  7  7  7  7  7
```

Here is a more pseudo-code like algorithm description:

1. Calculate SUM of all the elements
2. COUNT all the elements
3. If AVERAGE (SUM/COUNT) is not whole number, solution is not possible to achieve
4. STEPS = SUM(ABS(numberN - AVERAGE))/2
5. Each iteration, pick one number below AVERAGE and one above
6. Apply + operation to number below and - operation to number above
7. Repeat steps 5 and 6 until target achieved

Comment: Why bother with steps 5 & 6?  You know the average, you know how many steps it would take to get there, just set all values to the average and record/return the number of steps.

Comment: I'm assuming he wants the steps, otherwise yes, just set them all to the average.